# Cookie is being destroyed after reload

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a wordpress site, in which there is a form where the user gives the username and after submitting it he/she is being redirected to another page. In this page some user related data from the database is being displayed. I am trying to create a search form, which will display only the data related to the input of the form, like year or something.

Here is the code for the original form:

```
add_action('init', function () {
   $username = ( isset($_POST['luname']) ? $_POST['luname'] : '' );
   //$pass = ( isset($_POST['lupass']) ? $_POST['lupass'] : '' );
   setcookie("usernameCookie", $username, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

   if( isset( $_POST['mysubmitbtn'] ) ) {
      wp_redirect('http://mysite/somedata/');
      exit;
   }
});
```

Here is the code in the page where user is being redirected to :

```
<?php 
$s=$_COOKIE["usernameCookie"] ;
if ( username_exists( $s ) ) { 
   global $wpdb;
   echo "<b>user: ".$s."</b>";
   echo 
    '<form method="post" name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="srchbtn"/>
    </form>';
   $year = ( isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : '' );

   if( isset( $_POST['srchbtn'] ) ) {
       $year = $_POST['year'];
       $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select * From mytable Where user_login = %s and year = %d", $s, $year)); 
       foreach ( $results as $result ) { 
          echo 
            '<div style="text-align: left;"><br>
                <span style="font-family: Arial;">'.$result->description.'</span>
            </div>'; 
       }
   }
   else {
      $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("Select * From mytable Where user_login = %s", $s)); 
       foreach ( $results as $result ) { 
          echo 
            '<div style="text-align: left;"><br>
                <span style="font-family: Arial;">'.$result->description.'</span>
            </div>'; 
        } 
    } 
} 
else echo '
<h3 style="text-align: center; color: red;">Username '.$s.' does not exist.</h3>';

?>
```

The problem is if i refresh this page, the data are lost and "Username does not exist" is being displayed, so in order for the user to view the data he has to go back to the original page and submit the username again. This also happens if he submits a year in the form, so does't this mean that the cookie is being destroyed? Can anyone offer some thougths on why and how to get past the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init action is executed on every request. Your are overwriting it every time.

You should only set the cookie if there is a user, for example like this:

```
if ($username) {
  setcookie("usernameCookie", $username, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
```